Altering the query as OR instead of AND
I am working on shopify code with a custom theme and I suppose that the products on the collection page are exclusively dealt with javascript code.
Basically, the issue is that, whenever a second or third tag is picked from the menu instead of showing products with any of those tags, it attempts to show products that have all those tags at once.
For example, when the tags history and philosophy are picked, rather than showing all history and philosophy books together, the code fetches and features books that have both of these tags.
?constraint=history+philosophy

I understand that the issue is with the query, and if I could locate where it is taking place, I could probably just change an "AND" with an "OR."
Here is the jQuery snippet
$(document).on("click", ".dT_CollectionFilter", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var self = jQuery(this);
        var constraintValue = self.attr("data-value");

        if (self.hasClass("active")) {
            self.removeClass('active');
        } else {
            self.addClass('active');
        }

        //-- update search filter Constraint
        dTCollectionFilter.updateConstraint(constraintValue);


        //-- load collection grid
        dTCollectionFilter.updateCollectionGrid();

        showHideClearFilter();

    });

which triggers this javascript code
key: "updateCollectionGrid",
            value: function(e) {
                var t = this,
                    n = $("#dT_collectionGrid"),
                    i = $("#dT_collectionGrid").find("ul:first").attr("class"),
                    o = r.getConstraint(),
                    a = this.getCollectionWindowUrl() + "?";
                o.length > 0 && (a = a + "constraint=" + r.getConstraintQueryParams()), e && (a = a + "&" + dTGeneral.encodeQuery(e).toString()), dTGeneral.loadingAxiosCollectionFilterCreation(), axios.get(a).then((function(e) {
                    var t = e.data;
                    return t = t.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, "")
                })).then((function(n) {
                    return t.updateCollectionHistoryUrl(o, e), n
                })).then((function(e) {
                    $.parseHTML(e);
                    var t = $(e).find("#dT_collectionGrid").html();
                    n.html(t), $("#dT_collectionGrid").find("ul:first").attr("class", i), collectionFilterPostInit()
                }))

However I cannot see exactly where history+philosophy is broken into parts and run as history AND philosophy.
Basically, the issue is that, whenever a second or third tag is picked from the menu instead of showing products with any of those tags, it attempts to show products that have all those tags at once.
EDIT:
I think it is here, however when I alter "+" with "|" this time when more than one tag is selected all products are listed and nothing is excluded.
var r = new(function() {
    function e() {
        ! function(e, t) {
            if (!(e instanceof t)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
        }(this, e), this.constraint = [], this.DELIMITER = "+"
    }

Here is the code in its entirety
 var r = new(function() {
        function e() {
            ! function(e, t) {
                if (!(e instanceof t)) throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")
            }(this, e), this.constraint = [], this.DELIMITER = "+"
        }
        var t, i, o;
        return t = e, (i = [{
            key: "getConstraintQueryParams",
            value: function() {
                return this.constraint ? this.constraint.join(this.DELIMITER) : ""
            }
        }, {
            key: "getConstraint",
            value: function() {
                return this.constraint ? this.constraint : []
            }
        }, {
            key: "setConstraint",
            value: function(e) {
                this.constraint = e
            }
        }, {
            key: "updateConstraint",
            value: function(e) {
                var t = this.getConstraint(),
                    n = t.indexOf(e);
                return -1 === n ? t.push(e) : t.splice(n, 1), this.setConstraint(t)
            }
        }, {
            key: "removeConstraint",
            value: function(e) {
                var t = this.getConstraint();
                return t = this.remove(t, e), this.setConstraint(t)
            }
        }, {
            key: "resetConstraint",
            value: function() {
                return this.setConstraint([])
            }
        }, {
            key: "remove",
            value: function(e) {
                for (var t, n, r = arguments, i = r.length; i > 1 && e.length;)
                    for (t = r[--i]; - 1 !== (n = e.indexOf(t));) e.splice(n, 1);
                return e
            }
        }, {
            key: "updateCollectionHistoryUrl",
            value: function(e, t) {
                var n = "";
                if ("" == e) {
                    var i = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname;
                    n = "?"
                } else {
                    var o = r.getConstraintQueryParams();
                    i = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname + "?constraint=" + o
                }
                t && (i = i + n + "&" + dTGeneral.encodeQuery(t).toString()), window.history.replaceState({
                    path: i
                }, "", i)
            }
        }, {
            key: "getCollectionWindowUrl",
            value: function() {
                return window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + window.location.pathname
            }
        }, {
            key: "updateCollectionGrid",
            value: function(e) {
                var t = this,
                    n = $("#dT_collectionGrid"),
                    i = $("#dT_collectionGrid").find("ul:first").attr("class"),
                    o = r.getConstraint(),
                    a = this.getCollectionWindowUrl() + "?";
                o.length > 0 && (a = a + "constraint=" + r.getConstraintQueryParams()), e && (a = a + "&" + dTGeneral.encodeQuery(e).toString()), dTGeneral.loadingAxiosCollectionFilterCreation(), axios.get(a).then((function(e) {
                    var t = e.data;
                    return t = t.replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, "")
                })).then((function(n) {
                    return t.updateCollectionHistoryUrl(o, e), n
                })).then((function(e) {
                    $.parseHTML(e);
                    var t = $(e).find("#dT_collectionGrid").html();
                    n.html(t), $("#dT_collectionGrid").find("ul:first").attr("class", i), collectionFilterPostInit()
                }))
            }

Liquid code
<div class="container" data-section-id="{{ section.id }}" data-section-type="collection-template">            
  <div class="row">      
    {% if cart.attributes.pagination != blank and cart.attributes.pagination %}
    {% assign product_per_page = cart.attributes.pagination %}
    {% else %}
    {% assign product_per_page = section.settings.grid | times: section.settings.rows %}
    {% endif %}
    {% paginate collection.products by product_per_page %}  
    
    {%- unless settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'full_width' -%}
    {%- if settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'left' -%}
    {%- assign sidebarMode = 'left-sidebar' -%}
    {%- elsif settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'right' -%}
    {%- assign sidebarMode = 'right-sidebar' -%}
    {% endif %}
    {% endunless %}

    {% case section.settings.grid %}
    {% when '2' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'two-column' %}      
    {% assign imageSize = '585x686' %}      
    {% when '3' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'three-column' %} 
    {% assign imageSize = '380x446' %}      
    {% when '4' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'four-column' %}
    {% assign imageSize = '278x326' %}      
    {% when '5' %}
    {% assign grid_item_width = 'five-column' %}
    {% assign imageSize = '216x253' %}      
    {% endcase %}

    <div class="{{ column_style }} {{sidebarMode}} 
                {% if settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'full_width' %} no-sidebar{% endif  %}
                {%  unless settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'full_width' %}  
                    {% if settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'left' or settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'right'   %} has-sidebar {% endif %}  
                {% endunless %}">
      
      <div class="collection-grid product-grid-height-{{section.id}}">
        {% if section.settings.show_collection_image and collection.image %}
        <div class="collection-hero">
          <div class="collection-hero__image">           
            {%- assign img_url = collection.image  | img_url: '1x1' | replace: '_1x1.', '_{width}x.' -%}
              <img class="lazyload"
           src="{{ 'loading.gif' | asset_url }}"
                   data-src="{{ img_url }}"
                   data-widths="[180, 360, 470, 600, 770, 970, 1060, 1280, 1512, 1728, 2048]"
                   data-aspectratio="{{ collection.image.aspect_ratio }}"
                   data-sizes="auto"            
                   alt="{{ collection.title }}">            
              <noscript>
               {{ collection.image | img_url: '480x480', scale: 2 | img_tag: collection.title, 'dt-sc-noscript-image' }}
              </noscript>
          </div>  
          <div class="hero-header">
            <h2> {{ collection.title }} </h2>
            {% if collection.description != blank %}
            <div class="rte collection-description">
              {{ collection.description }}
            </div>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% if section.settings.collections_view_enable or section.settings.item_pre_view or section.settings.collections_sort_enable %}
        <div class="collection-header">            
          {% if section.settings.collections_view_enable %}
          {% render 'collection-mode', grid_item_width: grid_item_width %}
          {% endif %}            
          {% if section.settings.item_pre_view %}
          {% render 'collection-items-per-page' %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if section.settings.collections_sort_enable %}
          {% render 'collection-sorting' %}
          {% endif %}            
        </div>
        {% endif %}
        <div class="dT_VProdWrapper" id="dT_collectionGrid"> 
          <ul class="grid product-collection {{ rows }} dt-sc-column {{grid_item_width}} dt-even-columns">
            {% if collection.products.size > 0 %}                    
            {% for product in collection.products %}
            {% include 'product-grid-item', product: product, imageSize: imageSize %}
            {% endfor %}        
            {% else %}
            <li class="push">
              <p><em>{{ 'home_page.onboarding.no_products_html' | t }}</em></p>
            </li>
            {% endif %}
          </ul>

          {% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
          <div class="text-center pagination">
            {% include 'pagination' %}         
          </div>
          {% endif %}
        </div> 
      </div>

      {% if  settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'left' -%}
      {% include 'collection-sidebar' %}
      {% endif %}

      {% if  settings.collection_sidebar_use == 'right' -%}
      {% include 'collection-sidebar' %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>    
    {% endpaginate %}    
  </div>
</div>


There's no code here that's querying or filtering results. You'll need to find where axios is loading the data from. See where it says "axios.get(a)"? a is the url of where it loads the data from. You may need to pass different query params to the url, or edit the code at the url to get the results you want.

@admcfajn I think I found it, however, the problem subsists. Can you see my edited post?


"I think it is here, however when I alter "+" with "|" this time when more than one tag is selected all products are listed and nothing is excluded." - I think the | might break the rule completely and make the page try to load "cat1|cat2" instead of
"cat1"|"cat2".  Can you change  var r = new(function() { to  var r = new(function() { console.log('>>>',this) and show what that prints in console? I think we need to find what getConstraint outputs, what is this.constraint equal to? Is there maybe a setting in the Shopify admin where you can change that behavior?


@admcfajn came across no such setting on shopify admin and when I change the code as such it logs nothing into the console. I understand that this was a thing with older shopify themes.
"I think the | might break the rule completely and make the page try to load "cat1|cat2" instead of "cat1"|"cat2""
This is most likely the case, however, I have no clue as to how to deal with it.
